# Calculating the decay of a leveraged ETF

Tags: options

https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/thesis_Zhang.pdf

There is a formula given above but the immediate problem is that using the volatility for $\alpha$ tends to exaggerate decay since it's not uncommon for stocks to move very little despite the volatility being high. For example the SPX has a VIX of 12 despite the price barely changing .5% in a day.

The problem is that 3x ETFs reset daily, not inraday. This means you can tons of intraday volatility but if the prices keep ending unchanged, there will be no decay despite high volatility.

I think my version is more accurate:

$(\delta)^B(e^{(-dBt/360+o/2\ln(1-B^2p^2)-oB/2\ln(1-p^2))})$

t=o*7/5

o= number of trading days.

t=total number of days including weekends

B=leverage factor

d=dividend yield

p=daily price change

Comment: VIX is implied volatility, not actual vol.

Comment: VIX of 12 forecasts daily moves of +/- 0.75% based on $0.12/\sqrt{252}$

Comment: yeah .75 is way too high

Comment: The VIX is a 30day implied vol index